# How to read audio data (.wav) from azure blob storage using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

Hello fellow stackoverflowers.

I am having a problem with reading **audio data** from blob storage using pyspark. I am using databricks in my example.

UPDATED: I have gotten to this solution, that reads the data as raw **binaries**, but it seems that this solution is not optimal. The problem is, that pyspark is not created to work with audio files.

```
# Settings
storage_account_name = "storage_account_name"
blob_name = "blob_name" 
storage_account_access_key = "key"
file_name = "audio.wav"
file_type = "binaryFile"

#Spark confinguration and file location
spark.conf.set(
   "fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
   storage_account_access_key)
file_location = "wasbs://" + blob_name + "@" + storage_account_name + ".blob.core.windows.net/" + file_name
df = spark.read.format(file_type).load(file_location)
```

Afterwards you can read the data as following:

```
# Convert spark dataframe to pandas dataframe
df = df.toPandas()
# Sound player
from IPython.display import Audio, display
display(Audio(df['content'].iloc[0]))
```

[image: Audio player]

**Please upvote** if you found this helpful, took my time to share it with you.

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has solution in it too!

Comment: i still have a problem dealing with the binaries. For example to plot a spectogram I had to save the binary to wav file again and then do the plot